# how to get number from Promise<number>

Tags: react-native, api, promise

Hi i am new to react native. I am trying to extract the number from an api.Since my code is quite long, i try to include the relevant part here.The api returns a simple array(maybe json array, i'm not sure):[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLVIu.png)

```
    **Calls.js**
    
      const Calls= (user_id, symbol) => {
      const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      const getRecord = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            `http://myurl/user_id=${user_id}&symbol=${symbol}`
          );
          const json = await response.json();
          setData(json);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getRecord();
      }, []);
      return { data, isLoading };
    };
    
    **App.js**
export default Trading=()=>{

    const numberOfCallsApi = Calls(user_id, symbol);

          const renderItem = async (api) => {
            const [num, setnum] = useState(0);
            {
              (await api.isLoading) ? (
                <ActivityIndicator
                  color={colors.green}
                  style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
                />
              ) : (
                setnum(api.data[0].numberOfCalls)
              );
            }
            console.log(num);
            return num;
          };

          const b = renderItem(numberOfCallsApi);
          console.log(b);
};
```

The debugger shows that `console.log(num)=2` which is a number which I need, but **console.log(b)**
returns a promise [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gj9b.png). How can I make b to be a number?

Comment: please add numberOfCallsApi function...and the entire code were your calling console.log(b);

Comment: There are a lot of issues here and not enough code to see the full extent of what is going on. Await isLoading seems like a bad idea — isLoading should probably just be a Boolean state. Returning a component in one case and setting a variable in the other case doesn’t really make sense. API calls are commonly done in a useEffect, but again: not enough code to give a recommendation. Probably a good idea to rethink this design, though.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Since I am quite new to coding and not very understand the concept. I want to make the renderItem to be a component so that I can reuse it.